# Can we create multiple replica of docker container on docker desktop? How?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

i have windows server 2019 and i have installed docker desktop on the windows server , i tried creating multiple replica using docker compose and docker stack but the container doesn,t getting ports?

Suggest me best way to create replication of docker container on windows server

below is my YAML file

version: '3.8'

services:

app1:

```
image: tom1

deploy:

  replicas: 3

ports:

  - 8082:80

volumes:

  - D:\APP:C:\APP
```

using above 3 containers are getting created but the only one container get port

Comment: Docker Compose should be able to do this for you. Can you share the YAML file that you tried to use, so that we can investigate further?

Answer (score 0):

Use Docker Swarm for creating replicas of containers.

Or, You can use Docker Compose to define and manage multi-container applications.

Example :

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).